# unexpected css behaviour when an invalid character invalidates a declaration

Tags: css, debugging

I recently had an issue where a font-face declaration didn't work, my custom font was defaulting to arial for some reason. When I investigated it turned out that there was a stray invalid character before the font-face declaration

like this:

```
 v
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Somefont';
    src: url('somefont.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('somefont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('somefont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

So in this example the 'v' stops the font-face declaration from working, which makes sense. All the style declarations after this one work correctly, again as you'd expect.

MY question though relates to the fact that there was a valid comment in-between my invalid character and my style declarations, like this:

```
v
/* 
 * FONTS
 * ------------------------------------
 */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Somefont';
    src: url('somefont.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('somefont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('somefont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

So here is what I'm a little stuck on:

I would have expected the invalid 'v' character to do nothing, and for the comment (which is formatted correctly) to kind of reset the invalidity of the css and allow the first font-face to work as normal, much like in the first example where the first font-face declaration 'took the hit' and allowed the remaining css to work as normal.

its straight up css so there is no pre processor involvement.

Anyone with better css knowledge then me care to explain it?

**N.B. I am looking for the technical explanation as to why it allows a style declaration to reset/offset the invalid characters but not a comment, not how to avoid css errors/bugs**

Comment: Easy: validate your CSS **before** deploying it. By passing your problematic CSS (with the stray `v`) into [W3C's CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), you will get a parse error at line two.

Comment: Whilst I agree with your comment @Terry, I am trying to get to the bottom of why rather then avoidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy: validate your CSS **before** deploying it. By passing your problematic CSS (with the stray `v`) into [W3C's CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), you will get a parse error at line two.

The reason why the stray `v` invalidates your CSS file is because rules, when not separated by ';' and not terminated with '}', will be assumed to be contiguous until the next non-space character. Multiple white spaces will be seen as a single white space.

To better illustrate my points, all these lines are valid:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

body {
    height:
    100%
    padding: 20px
             10px;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px
             10px
}
```

---

Back to your question with why comments does not stop the propagation of a syntax error: Comments are completely ignored by the parser, so it does not prevent the syntax error from "propagating" even when it occurs upstream of the comment, i.e. the comment does not serve as a stop gap for earlier syntax errors.

Therefore, given your CSS code:

```
v
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Somefont';
    src: url('somefont.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('somefont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('somefont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

It is actually an equivalent of:

```
v @font-face {
    font-family: 'Somefont';
    src: url('somefont.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('somefont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('somefont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: The asker understands this. He's asking why the comment doesn't seem to stop the invalid token from breaking the `@font-face` rule.

Comment: The stuff about the white spaces and continuing the invalidity of the css untill the next non-space character is exactly what I was looking for, a great explination. Thanks

Comment: @atmd You're welcome - just updated my answer again, to illustrate how your stray v would look like as a machine parses it, in a human-understandable form :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking why the comment had no effect on the behaviour of the CSS, it's because that's exactly how comments should behave - including or removing comments from a stylesheet should not change it's interpretation in any way what so ever.  It's likely that comments are stripped from stylesheets before any parsing happens, which would explain the situation you have outlined.

Comment: makes sense. coupled with the answer on non-space characters I think that answers it perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's the fact that a comment is different from a declaration. The invalid character probably breaks the first declaration after it - the comment is simply passed over, so the break still happens at the next declaration.

Comment: That correct, it does break the font-face after the comment. but as I understood it comments are though ignored are still parsed by the browser in order to recognise it as a comment and ignore it. So I guess there must be a difference in the parsing of comments vs the parsing of valid css declarations

Comment: Exactly - that seems to be what is happening.